# Get wrong date from SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

In my asp.net web application with a SQL Server database, the date saved as `30/1/2014` and when I'm displaying it in asp.net page it display as `29/1/2014`

The strange thing when I open the table I found the date saved correctly as `30/1/2014`

The strange thing too, when I connect to the database from my local asp.net web application, everything is good, but the problem happens when publish the application although I use the same connection in local application and published application.

Please help me in this strange problem, thanks

Comment: This sounds like a UTC related problem, are you storing dates as UTC or Local time?

Comment: no i'm storing as datetime

Comment: *"are you storing dates as UTC or Local time?...no i'm storing as datetime*" - clearly you misunderstood the question. Is the date/time you are recording the current *local* time or is it the current *UTC* time?

Comment: i don't understand what utc time , but the date correctly stored , but the problem is when display

Comment: If you don't understand UTC and trying to store date/times then you have a much bigger problem. Please show the code in which you store the date and display the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you're storing the dates in a datetime field and your application is converting them to a different timezone.

30/1/2014 00:00 GMT+2 can become 29/1/2014 22:00 GMT.

Comment: but why every thing is correct when i connect to the same database from local application (before publishing)

Comment: becasue local application use same timezone as database and you only see the date part. Maybe the application is hiding the time?